# On browser back the previous value is resetting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a shopping cart application. After adding products to cart I am allowing the user to change the product quantity, which will effect the product total price and the grand total of the products. I am also having a text field for entering a coupon code and apply discount on the grand total. After which I am redirecting to a order summary page. If I use browser back button to go back to the cart list page, the changes I do in that page (like increasing/decreasing quantity, adding coupon code for discount, etc..) is not showing, instead it is showing me the price when I am first redirected to the cart list page with the initial quantity and price.

I am sharing my code below. Please help me out to understand a way to hold back my modifications while I am using the browser back button to return back to this page.

The price calculations are all done in that page's controller and the price update is done inside a watcher(which is a reason why I am not able to hold back the new modifications).

controller.js

```
// to get the price update when the cart list page is loaded from product list/details page
if($rootScope.cart.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.cart.length; i++) {
                $rootScope.products[i].p_price = $rootScope.products[i].p_quantity * $rootScope.products[i].p_originalprice;
                $rootScope.arrGrandTotal.push($rootScope.products[i].p_price);
                $scope.grandTotal += $rootScope.arrGrandTotal[i];
            }
            //$scope.totalUpdate = $scope.grandTotal;
            //console.log("$rootScope.grandTotal :"+$scope.grandTotal);
        }

// this function is fired when product quantity text field is updated with new product quantity
$scope.updateJson = function($index){               
            $rootScope.cart[$index].p_price = $rootScope.cart[$index].p_quantity * $rootScope.cart[$index].p_originalprice;
        }

// watching the array inside which the products added in cart are pushed. From this array I am getting the product price 
$scope.$watch('cart', function(newValue, oldValue){
            for(var i=0; i<$rootScope.cart.length; i++){
                if(newValue[i].p_price != oldValue[i].p_price){
                    if(newValue[i].p_price > oldValue[i].p_price){
                        $scope.grandTotal += (newValue[i].p_price - oldValue[i].p_price);
                    } else {
                        $scope.grandTotal -= (oldValue[i].p_price - newValue[i].p_price);
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }, true);
```

view.html

```
<input type="text" class="text-center form-control input-sm" ng-model="eachAddedProd.p_quantity" ng-change="updateJson($index)">

<div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h6 class="text-right">Do you have a coupon code? if not go <a href="https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=coupon+code" target="_blank">here</a></h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control coupon-entry" type="text" name="" value="" maxlength="9" ng-model="coupon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="row"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="couponCode()">Apply Code</button></div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <h4 class="text-right">Total <strong ng-class="{'old-price' : strikePrice}">{{grandTotal | currency}}</strong> <strong ng-hide="discountedPrice">{{discountPrice | currency}}</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="gotoInvoice()">
                            Checkout
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Let me know if I am clear with my problem, else you won't be able to find a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hold your value in the cookies or local storage.

Comment: I have tried this process but since the price update is occurring inside the watcher the new price is not working only when the watcher is working.

Answer (score 0):

**You can hold your value in the cookies or local storage.**